# Parse big JSON for reactive form

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I implements big reactive form on angular5. This form get data from JSON. I use formBuilder and several nested formGroups.

Every field have default value before rendering form. In console output form values after submit form.

CSS design is very simple.

[Live demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dr2ujy).

js:

```
  formData = {
    'Информация из КХД': {
      Марка: {
        type: 'input',
        value: 'qwerty',
      },
    'Модель': {
        type: 'select',
        value: ['wqeqwewq', 'sadasdasdda', 'xcvxcxcvxcv',],
        selected: 1,
      },
      'Год выпуска': {
        type: 'input',
        value: '',
      },
    },
    'Общая информация': {
      'ПТС': {
        type: 'input',
        value: 'qwerty',
      },
      'Пробег': {
        type: 'select',
        value: ['tgtrgrt', 'fdvdfvdf', 'csdcscsc',],
        selected: 2,
      },
      'Тип кузова': {
        type: 'select',
        value: ['sdv', '544564564', 'yjyujuyj',],
        selected: 0,
      },
    },
    // and more, more, more...
  }

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group(
      this.createForm(Object.keys(this.formData))
    );
  }

  createForm(fields) {
    const result = {};
    fields.forEach(field => {
      const fields = Object.keys(this.formData[field])
      result[field] = this.fb.group(this.createSubForm(field, fields));
    });
    return result;
  }

  createSubForm(field, fields) {
    const result = {};
    fields.forEach(f => {
      let fd = this.formData[field][f];
      if (fd.type === 'select') {
        result[f] = new FormControl(fd.value[fd.selected]);
      } else if (fd.type === 'input') {
        result[f] = new FormControl(fd.value);
      }      
    });
    return result;
  }

  getKeys() {
    return Object.keys(this.form.controls);
  }

  getSubKeys(key) {
    const subControls = this.form.get(key).value;
    return Object.keys(subControls);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('form submitted', this.form.value);
  }
```

html:

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="key" *ngFor="let key of getKeys()">
    <h1 class="head">{{key}}</h1>

    <div class="subKey" *ngFor="let subKey of getSubKeys(key)" [formGroupName]="key">
      <label>{{subKey}}</label>

      <input type="text" [formControlName]="subKey" *ngIf="formData[key][subKey].type === 'input'">

      <select [formControlName]="subKey" *ngIf="formData[key][subKey].type === 'select'">
        <option 
          *ngFor="let item of formData[key][subKey].value; let i = index" 
          [value]="item">
          {{ item }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div> 
  </div>  

  <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

scss:

```
.head {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.key {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

    .subKey {
        width: 47%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 15px;

        >* {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an unusual approach, it's very cryptic and as a result will be a bad maintenance of the code in the future, if in the future you wanna add some custom validators, style or add some dependent validators or other things will became a chimera this component, definetly will kill productivity on quick prototyping. If you wanna handle a big bulks of forms, i suggest you to look at using a [dynamic form](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).